# Rails: redirecting a percentage of users to beta version of app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app. When the user.id is even, I want to redirect the user from myapp.com/* to beta.myapp.com/*

I'm thinking I could put a before hook in application_controller.rb but I'm not sure how to do the wildcard redirect (any time an even ID user visits a page on myapp.com, they are redirected to the same page on beta.myapp.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `request.path` to redirect to the same path on a different domain

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
before_action :toggle_redirect

def toggle_redirect
  if current_user.id.even? && request.url == "http://www.myapp.com/"
    redirect_to "http://www.beta.myapp.com#{request.path}"
  end
end
```

Comment: @JacksonCunningham You might want to consider only doing this on GET requests. And maybe only those without query params.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom. When is a use case this would come up? First time an even id'd user hits the site will be a GET request (which switches them to beta.myapp.com) and from then on they will be submitting POSTs through the beta version. I don't understand how they'd be able to POST without first being redirected

Comment: @JacksonCunningham User visits www. User goes to lunch. OP implements beta redirect. User comes back and submits form. Might not be relevant, but then again it might.